# Lua How to calculate with index?

Tags: lua

I want to write a function but I dont know how to do it.

```
local data ={
[100000000]='string1',
[250000000]='string2',
[500000000]='string3',
}

local calc=780325665
```

I want to calculate each one of data index with calc, for exmaple

```
result= calc-(500000000+250000000)
```

I like to reward result and data[500000000],data[250000000]= string1 and string2

```
local calc=780325665
for ind,i in pairs(data) do
    repeat
        if calc< 0 then return end
        print(calc,data[ind])
        calc=calc-ind
    until calc < ind
end
```

it does not work as I would like, I would like it as in my example

### I hope someone can help me.

I want to create a function that calculates how many official amount paid in a total number. These numbers should be returned to me. for example. I have 10, 25, 50 and a total number 380

```
so 385 = (7*50) + (3*10) rest 5

local calc=780325665 --only example number
so i have 100000000,250000000,500000000 and total number calc

calc-(500000000+250000000) rest 30325665 because there are no smaller number
```

I will reward those 2 numbers depending on how often it can be shortened

Comment: Could you please show the expected output, I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Instead of using unrealistically large values, please explain your procedure using smaller values? Such as 10, 25, 50 and 380 as stated in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have gotten your question right - the following code should work for you -

```
local data ={
[1]='string1',
[2]='string2',
[10]='string4',
[25]='string3',
}

-- lets get the indices in their increasing order
local indices = {}
for n in pairs(data) do table.insert(indices, n) end
table.sort(indices, function(a, b) return a > b end)

local calc = 97
local result = {}

-- for every index, highest coming first
for _,v in ipairs(indices) do
    -- if calc is bigger than this index
    while calc >= v do
        -- if this index has never been encountered, set it to 1 or add 1 to previous
        result[v] = (result[v] or 0) + 1
        -- reduce calc and check again
        calc = calc - v
    end
end

-- result is your output
```

If this is not what you were looking for, please edit your question to provide more details.  Possibly with an example.

Comment: `result[v] = (result[v] or 0) + 1` can replace the entire `if-else-end` block.

Comment: incorporated hjpotter92's suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but try this:

```
1. Get rid of "repeat" and "until calc<ind"
2. Change "if calc <0" to "if calc<ind"
```

Perhaps you could add a few more examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count and calculate all numbers In a table then this might be useful:

```
local count = 0
for k, v in pairs(data) do
     count = count + 1
end

local total = 0
for i = 1, count do
   total = total + data[i]
end
```

This simple code might help you to count all numbers Inside your table and calculate them.